# Trying to infer model parameter of Lotka-Volterra model

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, ode

```
def derivative(X, t, A, B, C, D):
    x, y = X
    dotx = x * (A - B * y)
    doty = y * (-D + C * x)
    return np.array([dotx, doty])

def integration(t,A,B,C,D,X0):
    res = odeint(derivative, X0, t, args = (A,B,C,D))
    return res

X0 = [30, 4]

X = array([[30. ,  4. ],
       [47.2,  6.1],
       [70.2,  9.8],
       [77.4, 35.2],
       [36.3, 59.4],
       [20.6, 41.7],
       [18.1, 19. ],
       [21.4, 13. ],
       [22. ,  8.3],
       [25.4,  9.1],
       [27.1,  7.4],
       [40.3,  8. ],
       [57. , 12.3],
       [76.6, 19.5],
       [52.3, 45.7],
       [19.5, 51.1],
       [11.2, 29.7],
       [ 7.6, 15.8],
       [14.6,  9.7],
       [16.2, 10.1],
       [24.7,  8.6]])

t = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0]

XData = t
YData = X

curve_fit(integration,XData,YData)
```

So X is my data, the first column is species x, and second column is species y.
I tried to infer parameters for this Lotka-Volterra model using ode and curve fit.
The error says not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
I am actually not even sure whether I should infer parameter this way.

Can anyone help me with this, are there any better methods of infering parameters.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note that in `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`both arguemnts `xdata` and `ydata` are required to be flat arrays, you use a multi-dimensional structure. While it is strongly suggested that `xdata` contains one input value or vector per element of `ydata`, there is no requirement for it. `xdata` is a constant that could also have been passed some other way. It is there just for the convenience in standard regression tasks, so a complete change in the input data can be effected in one location by just changing these two arrays.

Thus it is also no problem to have `ydata` twice as long as `xdata`. Just apply `.flatten()` to the 2-dimensional arrays.

Next, the parameter list has to be a list of scalars, so add `Y0` and pass the initial vector `[X0,Y0]`.

Together these corrections and changes to your code lead to a "result". Which is not very convincing.

I got a better result, but still not perfect, in using a multiple shooting approach, taking the points in `X[:-1]` and integrating for the time step `1`, comparing the collected list of end-points to `X[1:]`. This works better in finding parameters that match amplitude and frequency, but produces a slight speed difference that looks better with a 3% correction of the coefficients.

One would probably need a mix of both approaches to get the local as well as global characteristics respected.

[image: plots of the fitted solution]

And indeed, this combined approach works, giving parameters

```
A,B = 0.5215206964006734,  0.02567364947581818
C,D = 0.02493663631623848, 0.8476224408838039

X0,Y0 =  34.53872014350661, 4.653177640949391
```

---

**Code for that combined fitting program:** For the residual computation, first encapsulate the solver to avoid repetition of solver parameters. Then use that to first integrate over the full interval with the variable initial point, and then over the time step 1 segments.

```python
def solver(XY,t,para): 
    return odeint(derivative, XY, t, args = para, atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-11)

def integration(XY_arr,*para):
    XY0 = para[4:]
    para = para[:4]
    T = np.arange(len(XY_arr))
    res0 = solver(XY0,T, para)
    res1 = [ solver(XY,[t,t+1],para)[-1] 
             for t,XY in enumerate(XY_arr[:-1]) ]
    return np.concatenate([res0,res1]).flatten()
```

This obviously needs the reference array prepared in a similar fashion

```
XData = X
YData = np.concatenate([ X,X[1:]]).flatten()

p0 =[ 0.5215,  0.02567,  
      0.02493,  0.8476,
      34.53, 4.653]
```

After that the curve fitting procedure call remains the same, all changes happened before

```
params, info = curve_fit(integration,XData,YData,p0=p0)
XY0, para = params[4:], params[:4]
print(XY0,tuple(para))

t_plot = np.linspace(0,len(X),500)
x_plot = solver(XY0, t_plot, tuple(para))
```